# Python Pandas Lambda rows renaming of anonymous functions?

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I want to rename the quantile functions with Q10 and Q90 to the pandas result.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
quantile10 = lambda myDf :  myDf.quantile(q=0.10)
quantile90 = lambda myDf :  myDf.quantile(q=0.90)
df.agg([min,max, np.median, np.std, pd.DataFrame.mean, quantile10, quantile90])
```

[image]

where I expect each `<lambda>` to be `Q10` and `Q90`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__name__`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

quantile10 = lambda myDf :  myDf.quantile(q=0.10)
quantile10.__name__ = 'Q10'
quantile90 = lambda myDf :  myDf.quantile(q=0.90)
quantile90.__name__ = 'Q90'

df = df.agg([min,max, np.median, np.std, pd.DataFrame.mean, quantile10, quantile90])

print (df)

               B         C         D         E
min     4.000000  2.000000  0.000000  2.000000
max     5.000000  9.000000  7.000000  9.000000
median  4.500000  5.500000  2.000000  4.500000
std     0.547723  2.880972  2.714160  2.483277
mean    4.500000  5.500000  2.833333  4.833333
Q10     4.000000  2.500000  0.500000  2.500000
Q90     5.000000  8.500000  6.000000  7.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html), pass to `agg` a dict of column names and functions.

```
df.agg({"quantile10": quantile10, .... })
```